# Jquery ajax call works only on first page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, python-2.7

I'm trying to implement the following code which should create a text field and a button.  Then I want to use the ajax call to run my python script.  But for some reason the ajax call fails with the following code:

```
<div id=myapp-content data-role="page">

    <form id="fome" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="gettable" value="">
     <button>SUBMIT</button>
    </form>

    <script>
    database = 'localhost:28017';
    $('button').click(function (){

        var input_val_from_button = document.getElementsByName("gettable")[0].value;
        console.log("Value Entered: " + input_val_from_button);

        var results;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
```

I did manage to get ajax to work by replacing the button tag with an input tag but that made javascript run the ajax code every time I clicked the textfield.  So instead of the button I had this:

```
<input type="submit" name="command" value="SUBMIT">

</form>
        <script>
        database = 'localhost:28017';
        $('button').click(function (){
```

Any ideas as to how I can get ajax to work?  I need it to run after the button click.

Here is more of the ajax part:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "service/findRecord/"+input_val_from_button,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
                            //do some stuff...
            },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log("Ajax error");
            console.log("xhr status: "+xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        },
        complete: function(){console.log("Finish ajax");}
    });

})
</script>
```

Comment: some your code is discarded. Show all the lines in your code.

Comment: I just showed the relevant parts.  But I can include more

Comment: @user2099522, what does `ajax fails` mean? It is not executed, or throws an error, etc?

Comment: Oh, I meant it returns an error.  I print xhr.status, and it gives status zero meaning response text empty

Comment: The thrown error is blank but it gets to the error section in my ajax call where I print some error message.  Here I'll add the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that after the click on the button it submits the form. This is because default type of `<button>` is `submit`, so actualy your markup equals to this:

```
<form id="fome" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="gettable" value="">
    <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

To fix this simply prevent default behavior of the button in the hanler:

```
$('button').click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // rest of the code unchanged
```